# Alpha Bug in the Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency

I have a problem in the compositor.
The alpha looks kinda glitched. The only way to solve it was to convert the file to TIFF.
Is this a knewn Bug in this Blender Version (3.6.1)?

When i open it in windows itself or in photoshop it looks fine. Only in Blender it looks like this.

[image: Original Image]

[image]

Comment: You have to use an _Alpha Over_ node in the _Compositor_ and either enable _Convert Premultiplied_ in the node or set the _Premultiplied_ factor to 1.

Comment: That worked! Thanks alot! Because i watched a tutorial and there they didnt even used that. Just the image and then they linked it to the "composite" & "Viewer" node without any glitches at all. Thanks Gordon!

Comment: You could also disable _Convert Premultiplied_ and leave _Premultiplied_ factor at 0, and instead plug the alpha output of the image into the _Fac_ input of the _Alpha Over_ node.

Comment: Okey it still dont work. It just worked right now because i also rendered one image out as exr. Its still not working with the PNG. So yeah in that tutorial its working, going from the image directly into the viewer/composite Node. "use Alpha" is activated. 

Like i said when i take the png, convert it into a tiff file it works.

Comment: Well, I did it with a PNG and no EXR. Just using _Alpha Over_ node to place the PNG over either a color, another image or (if you want a transparent background) a render layer with a transparent background. I do not know what exactly you are doing. Or you have to link the tutorial to see what they are doing.

Comment: Its the "Master 3D Environments in Blender" its not for free i cannot really link a video. But he also includes the project and when i open it it has the same problem. So it really looks like its a Bug in this Version. What i now did i converted my PNG's to TIFF and now it works fine without any nodes in between. Here is also a image how it looks in his Video https://imgur.com/a/0Z42gk4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial (I have the same course) is using an older version of Blender. As you can see in the screenshot in your comments, the *Image Sequence* node does not even have a field below the *Color Space* option where you can switch the *Alpha*.

To use the alpha channel of the PNG image, you can plug it into a *Set Alpha* node with the default *Mode*: *Apply Mask*. The *Image* output then produces an image with "correct" transparency.

[image: set alpha]

By the way, if anyone is interested in the tutorial on compositing, Martin has uploaded that part as a free tutorial on Youtube where he is using Blender version 3.0.0 Alpha: [Introduction to Compositing in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIZrTXtyQkY)

As you can see there, his transparency looks the same as yours before he is using *Alpha Over* nodes with *Convert Premultiplied* enabled:

[image: alpha in tutorial]

Comment: Okay thanks! Yeah the Tutorial is with an older Version but i will also check out his free Video you linked! Thanks Gordon its working now with the png!

Comment: @hummingbrd Glad I could figure it out. If it helped you, you might consider accepting the answer so other users can find it, too.